# Is there a way to override and not execute the headerCallBack in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I've created an abstract parentFlatFileWriter where I included the headerCallBack to a default header.  This works great because I'm writing to 6 files.

But, on one file I'm writing, I want to skip the header for that one file. I still want to use the abstract bean for all the rest of the outfiles.

Can I override the inherited headerCallBack property and not write the header?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header will be written only is `FlatFileItemWriter.headerCallback` property is setted else header writing is skipped. In your 7th writer just set `FlatFileItemWriter.setHeaderCallback(null)`.
In Spring XML write:

```
<bean id="my7thwriter" class="My7thWriterImpl" parent="parentFlatFileWriter">
  <property name="headerCallBack"><null/></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you.  Perfectamundo.